# Div mouseover events not firing when using WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I'm using a separate `div` to hold a bunch of smaller `div`s, each to be used as text labels. Everything is supposed to sit above a WebGL canvas.

I want these label `div`s to trigger mouseover and mouseout events, but I've tried a bunch of different ways and I still can't get these events to fire.

Using the developer console in Chrome I can see that the functions are assigned to the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` properties but they are never called.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/1danielcoelho/pen/VQxwBz) with full html, js and css that I forked from [Damien Clarke](https://codepen.io/dxinteractive) and very lightly modified. I expected stuff to be printed to the console when mousing over the labels, but nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `pointer-events: none;` in the stylesheet for your labels. Therefore they get no events.

You can get most of the effects of `pointer-events: none` with `preventDefault` in the right event handlers instead. (You may need to modify the standard Three.js OrbitControls you are using to get the exact behavior you want.)